# Execute VSPackage command After build

Tags: msbuild, vspackage

I have created new VSPackage.

Code from VST file:

```
<Buttons>
  <Button guid="guidAlgoPackCmdSet" id="BuildAlgo" priority="0x0100" type="Button">
    <Parent guid="guidAlgoPackCmdSet" id="AlgoPackMenuGroup" />
    <Icon guid="guidImages" id="bmpPic1" />
    <Strings>
      <CommandName>CustomCommondName</CommandName>
      <ButtonText>Build Custom</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Button>
```

How can I reference this command in AfterBuild section?

Next configuration:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="CustomCommondName" />
</Target>
```

returns 9009 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround and it suites me even better cuz gives me much more information.

```
private void SubscribeToBuildEvents()
{
    var dte = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));
    _buildEvents = dte.Events.BuildEvents; //we have to save the reference in order to keep events firing
    dte.Events.BuildEvents.OnBuildProjConfigDone += BuildEvents_OnBuildProjConfigDone;

}
private void BuildEvents_OnBuildProjConfigDone(string project, string projectConfig, string platform, string solutionConfig, bool success)
{
   //fires for each built project
}
```